# Grand Theft Auto V vs GTA Online

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[image]

**Problem:** At present there is no `[gta-online]` tag, as some moderators have been actively removing it from questions when it has been used, forcing those with questions relating to this online game to use `[grand-theft-auto-v]`, making no distinction between the two very different games.

Obviously **GTA Online** is only available with a purchase and installation of **Grand Theft Auto V**, but shouldn't there be some way to filter these questions?

Suggestion:

- [grand-theft-auto-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5) refers to the single player game starring Michael, Franklin and
  Trevor.
- [gta-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-online) refers to the persistent online world of GTA.

Whatever the consensus, these are essentially two different games with questions that don't relate to each other, so I believe there should be *some* way to separate them.

Also, seeing their obvious differences, it would make sense for the use of one tag or the other, but not both (unless the question really does relate to both games).

---

**More information on what GTA Online is:**

As this discussion has progressed it's made me aware of how people are misunderstanding what *GTA Online* is. The fact that it's including with *Grand Theft Auto V* has led to some assuming that it's directly connected with that game. Just an add-on. The multiplayer aspect of the single player game.

In reality Rockstar have done something (as far as I'm aware) unprecedented: *GTA Online* is actually more like an entirely separate MMO that just happens to use the same assets as GTAV. And yes, they've essentially given it away "free" with GTAV. (Although, don't be fooled, they're expected to earn [$100 million directly from *GTA Online* alone](http://www.vg247.com/2013/10/02/gta-5-will-make-437-million-from-dlc-microtransactions-analyst/).)

For those who haven't experienced it yet, the important thing to remember is that *GTA Online* is a completely separate game, designed to be [tweaked, maintained and expanded by Rockstar for years to come](http://www.oxm.co.uk/60520/gta-online-will-expand-forever-rockstar-will-add-new-locations-including-old-stuff/). It is not dependent on the original game, and advice for progressing in it will be completely different to advice for progressing in *Grand Theft Auto V*.

One way of looking at it is this: *GTA Online* is to *Grand Theft Auto V* what *The Old Republic* is to *Knights of the Old Republic*. The only difference is that *GTA Online* uses the same assets and engine as GTAV, and was given away with that game.

Or as President of Rockstar North, Leslie Benzie, put it:

> **"Grand Theft Auto Online is a different entity, a separate thing. It's not part of GTAV. It'll grow on its own..."**

Source: http://www.computerandvideogames.com/423020/gta-v-interview-rockstar-north-president-leslie-benzies-on-gta-online/

They're different games.

Comment: I note that a user voted to reject the relevant edit, claiming the existence of a `[gta-online]` tag and its rejection by the community, but I can't find any evidence of such -- I can only see questions formerly tagged `[grand-theft-auto-5][online]` (and maybe `[multiplayer]`). Can anyone point me to the discussion specifically about `[gta-online]` for the sake of being informed?

Comment: As far as I know, there hasn't been a formal discussion of it.  We do, however, have a "rockstar-social-club" tag, and [we've removed gta-online](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/133050/revisions) from other questions already.  Seems a tad redundant to use both.

Comment: Rockstar-social-club is an entirely different beast than gta-online.

Comment: Don't use [online], it's a tag simile to [multiplayer] anyway.  Having said that, if the users who play the game wish to have separate tags, I support [gta-online] as long as the tag wiki excerpts are clear on their use.

Comment: I'm absolutely speechless that anyone could be under the impression that Rockstar Social Club is synonymous with GTA Online. RSC is a website which (amongst other things) helps users track their progress in Red Dead Redemption, LA Noire, Max Payne 3, Midnight Club Los Angeles, Grand Theft Auto IV, etc. etc. Perhaps you should read this @fbueckert: http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/about

Comment: The tag came into being right around the same time GTA V came out.  I equated it to being used for GTA Online.  And all I'm saying is, we've already removed the gta-online tag from other questions.  That's my input into this discussion.  I don't care one way or the other what we use, so long as it's consistent.

Comment: @fbueckert It seems that some overzealous moderating has caused this problem, then. The community created `[GTA-Online]` for a good reason. At present the only way to distinguish between the two games is to put "[(not GTA Online)](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133845/becoming-in-a-billionaire-in-gtav-not-gta-online)" in the question's title!

Comment: So let's discuss what needs to be done. Don't retag using gta-online, or make edits based on the assumption that we WILL use the tag, until the discussion has run its course, and the community has decided on a plan of action.

Comment: @fbueckert Ok, so is this just a waiting game then? (Waiting for input from other members?) As there doesn't seem to be much to discuss at present.

Comment: You can use `[tag:tagname]` to markdown a tag

Comment: The tag is currently [tag:grand-theft-auto-5] and I think it should be kept that way (for consistency) instead of making it V.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Yes.  I don't care which way we go, but I do care if a user unilaterally decides to change it after asking about it on Meta.  If no one weighs in on either side for a couple days, then I'd say go ahead.

Comment: No, you got two users to approve your edit. Anyone can create a tag; I (or anyone else) can just as easily remove it. Two users approving an edit does not indicate community consensus.

Comment: @fbueckert I meant its *initial* creation and use.

Comment: @fbueckert Hmm. Maybe it wasn't that widespread until recently. Although some users have been calling for it, it seems: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133810/can-you-use-ammu-nation-shooting-ranges-in-gta-online

Comment: If [tag:grand-theft-auto-5-ifruit] gets a tag (with all of three questions) then [tag:gta-online] really needs its own tag!

Comment: It seems the people who are opposing this are those who haven't actually played GTA Online :-/ Is it unreasonable to ask people without direct experience to not throw their oar in?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Yes, that is unreasonable.  There is more to this than game knowledge.  MUCH more.

Comment: @fbueckert Yes, you need to have knowledge and experience of this site, but without knowledge and experience of the games in question *as well*, how can you have an informed opinion?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt No, it's not.  Game knowledge is *useful*, and can help, but the whole point of tagging is to help the site.  There's a reason tagging comes at a higher privilege level.  More goes into it than knowing about the game, and it's disrespectful to users to go, "You don't play the game, so your opinion doesn't count."  That invalidates whatever experience they bring to the table.

Comment: @fbueckert I never said anything of the sort! I merely asked if it would be unreasonable to ask those who had zero knowledge of the game in question to not participate. And it was said out of frustration, with the aim of making people aware that this is quite possible a gaming first, and not really a serious attempt at precluding people from the discussion. (Sorry that wasn't clear.) Unfortunately, in this case, without appreciation of how this situation is unique, input is coming from a place of ignorance, which isn't helping anything :-/

Comment: Except it's *not* ignorance.  It's a different perspective.  I'm pretty sure this isn't a gaming first, and especially if it is, excluding people on the basis they haven't played this does the site a great disservice.  That's why I'm saying it's unreasonable.  Rather than implying that those who haven't played it should butt out, why not TELL us what those differences are?  *That's* reasonable.  What you're asking is not.

Comment: @fbueckert I have tried to do just that, in the original question.

Comment: But ARE they really different games?  I've read that a patch for GTA 5 closes some exploits in GTA Online.  That implies a degree of interconnectivity.  The fact that the GTA 5 disc must be in the drive to play GTA Online also implies that there are some dependencies.  You may think it's black and white; I don't think it's quite that clear cut.

Comment: A question was asked recently that is a good example for this debate. See my comment on [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/133949/5291). What would be your response? Please ask a new question? What should the new question be tagged? Or am I stuck waiting for a response to a comment that is much less likely to be seen?

Comment: @fbueckert Doesn't matter. Community considers them separate. Tag folksonomies are not dictated to the community, the community generates the tag folksonomy. Consider this: is DayZ the same as Arma 2? No. But they use the same executable. The only difference is the content that is loaded and played, which is the same as GTAV/GTAO.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie And I'm fine with that.  I'm challenging the (unreasonable) assumption that only those who have played it should be participating in this discussion.  There's enough information out there for us to make an informed decision, whether we've played it or not.

Comment: @fbueckert No dispute there! I'm specifically responding to [this comment](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7760/grand-theft-auto-v-vs-gta-online#comment22697_7760).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie And that comment is part and parcel of the argument; dismissing the opposing viewpoint because it doesn't agree with you is exactly the problem.  I'm pointing out that a case can be made for the other viewpoint.  It's not that farfetched.

Comment: @fbueckert I think the emerging/ed consensus is that they are distinct games, sharing an executable/launcher/engine. I think the "can people who haven't played debate this?" is a non-issue since the Arqade community doesn't support it, nor would the site function if we started enforcing such an idea. It only ever gets expressed by new users, and it never gains support.

Comment: Maybe the [grand-theft-auto-5-ifruit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5-ifruit) tag should be questioned as well.  Perhaps it should be lumped under one of these.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt You can stop throwing fresh logs on the fire now. Thanks. :)

Comment: I believe your last comment would be considered "stoking the fire", @sevensideddie According to fbueckert, Metal Gear Solid 2 and 3 are the same game because they were released on the same disc with the same launcher. It's a maddening logic.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt What? That doesn't even make sense... now you are just making a stupid comment to prove he is wrong... Metal gear solid 2 and 3 were not released on the same date... 2001 and 2004. Just because they made a compilation of the game doesn't mean they are the same...

Comment: @Lyrion Technically speaking, GTAV and GTA Online were not released on the same date, either, btw.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt There is a difference between being on the same disc, and comming from 2 different sources, GTAV and GTA online are the same game. 1 is offline and the other is online, they use the same sources, the graphics are the same. Just gameplay differences here and there. MGS2 and MGS3 used different graphics, because the third came 3 years after the second. But who cares? They already split it up, you got what you wanted, I don't see the point of just continuing this debate. Just let it go.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt I think my simile may have been unclear, and for that I apologise. To clarify "fire" = fbueckert and others in these comments, "logs" = continued antagonising. Stop antagonising fbueckert and others. As you can see, your argument in these comments is *pointless*, as it is already being debated fruitfully within the answers and votes.

Comment: You're arguing pointlessly. You're welcome to continue arguing pointlessly, but it won't win any friends, allies, or arguments, and tends rather to attract more antagonists. I agree with your position and have voted accordingly, so consider it as advice with shared interests rather than orders from an enemy.

Comment: This is me nodding, smiling, and backing away.

Comment: Fun fact, as of 2020 GTAV made $1.09 billion https://www.tweaktown.com/news/58516/gta-online-earned-1-09-billion-analyst-firm/index.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Edited to add: My last sentence in the original answer below is really the most important aspect and I wanted to elaborate.

[grand-theft-auto-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5) and [gta-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-online) are **DIFFERENT GAMES**, and should be tagged accordingly.

Even the president of Rockstar North says so in [an interview with CVG](http://www.computerandvideogames.com/424569/gta-online-to-launch-2-weeks-after-gta-5/).

> He explained: "It'll be GTA Online; it's not part of GTA 5. Obviously it's set in the GTA 5 engine, but it's going to grow and evolve into its own thing." Access to GTA Online will come for free with every retail copy of GTA 5.

I don't think it's a stretch of the imagination to believe that GTAO will be released on it's own someday. I know Rockstar's current position is that won't be happening, but policies change - after all they don't want to discourage anyone from buying GTAV at full price.

Also, GTAO has a high potential to be patched and changed over time, making the divide between the two games ever larger.

If I play GTAV on Xbox but don't have a Gold subscription, I'm not going to care about GTAO questions and answers. If such a question was only tagged with [grand-theft-auto-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5) and did not specify game mode, I could actually be *misinformed*, which is the last thing we want to happen here on arqade.

Isn't the most basic test for if two tags are both useful whether a user would want to subscribe to one, but ignore the other?

> [I only bought GTA 5 for online play](http://gtaforums.com/topic/612292-create-character-wont-save/)
>
> [I only bought gta 5 for the story line](http://forum.bodybuilding.com/showthread.php?t=157170003&p=1138777553&viewfull=1#post1138777553)

It may not be everyone, but it's not unreasonable.

---

I think [gta-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-online) and [grand-theft-auto-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5) should be separate tags.

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131522/whats-the-fastest-easiest-way-to-level-up-your-skills) stands out specifically. [This other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/133663/how-do-i-change-my-character-stats-after-starting-in-gta-online?lq=1) was asked and quickly closed as a duplicate, but from my time playing GTA Online I don't think it is a valid duplicate.

In story mode you can increase your skills by going to a shooting range and earning medals in challenges. But in online mode there are no medals since the shooting range is a competitive sport. Do you gain the same skill increase by winning a challenge as earning a medal? Also, online mode introduces new job types. Does winning a race increase your driving skill? Does participating in Arm Wrestling (completely new event type) increase your strength?

Certainly the existing answer at the first question could be updated to fit both game modes. But wait, there's more!

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131250/how-does-the-garage-system-work-in-gta-v) asks about garages. Garages in story mode are very different from garages in Online mode. The exact same question would have different answers for GTAV vs. GTAO.

In fact, I can think of many potential questions that would have completely different answers in the two game modes (some of which have been asked in some form or another). How do I save my progress? How do I unlock [weapon X]? Is there any risk to stealing cars? What's the best way to make money?

Different users are going to focus on one mode or another. It isn't realistic to expect everyone to answer for both game modes.

Comment: So, effectively, Rock Star has created GTA5, which is not only a stand-alone game, but they're also using it as an engine and client to run a separate MMO called GTO. Yeah, that sounds like we need two tags for two different things.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yeah, that's essentially what they've done. It's quite a shrewd business move, too, given the planned microtransactions: Create a "lite" MMO using the engine/assets, give away a copy for free to everyone who buys GTAV, and (hopefully) earn a ton more money through microtransactions. Estimated income from this plan? [$100 million over five years](http://www.vg247.com/2013/10/02/gta-5-will-make-437-million-from-dlc-microtransactions-analyst/). Not too shabby!

Comment: I'd also like to add that some time spent searching online makes it appear that the gaming community at large considers GTAV and GTA Online to be separate games (this includes both gamers and the media). Rockstar seems to have similiar feelings.

Comment: @Wipqozn That's one of the reasons why I put the two logos in the original question: Rockstar most certainly does not see them as being the same thing.

Comment: You stole my thoughts! I was editing in the same thing as you guys commented :)

Answer (score -5):

I don't think there's enough of a difference to have two different tags. Whatever R*s marketing, they are both GTA5. We don't have separate tags for the single- and multi-player elements of Starcraft 2, even when they need vastly different strategies.

People can identify in their question whether they're talking about the single- or multi-player.

Comment: The problem with this view point, is that the mechanics in each game are different, with a future content strategy quoted by Rockstar which will differentiate them further. The developer calls them two separate games, the media calls them two separate games, so should we.

Comment: The mechanics aren't really that different. Other than a few instances (ie, property ownership) there's not really much between them.

Comment: Another person who sounds like he's going purely by what they've read...?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt No, actually, going by what I've played of the game. I don't think the online component is different enough for us to call it two different games.

Comment: Seemingly, the *entire* games industry, the developer, and the fans of the game disagree that they're the same game.

Comment: @TZHX Interesting. I'm glad you've at least played it, but I'm surprised you don't considered them vastly different. I also don't get the comparison with SC2.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt SC2 has single-player and multi-player components. Questions about MP don't necessarily relate to SP and vice versa. That's where the comparison comes from. The differences are either in things that do/don't exist in one or the other, the mechanics of shooting, driving, basic mission progression don't work *dramatically* differently in online opposed to the main game. No need to be agressive/hosile/rude.

Comment: @kalina the developer says they're different for marketing, the media repeat what the developers say, the "fans" (rather than people who just played and liked the game) rabidly repeat whatever R* tell them.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Please stop assuming people answering don't know what they are talking about. It is rude and disrespectful.

Comment: @kalina - whilst I agree on the whole, I don't think we should be basing our decision on what Rockstar say they might do in the future. GTA online needs to stand alone in the here and now, no matter what promises are made or how much 'content is in the pipeline'. At the end of the day rockstar are out to make money - if GTA online is not commercially viable they'll kill it off and cut their losses in a heartbeat

Comment: @Robotnik re-read everything I've said, conclude that I'm saying there should be two tags, stop asking me why I'm disagreeing with you, resolved.

Comment: @kalina - Wow. Chill out man, I wasn't being hostile. Like I said I agree with you (there should be two tags), just not with your reasoning about future promises made by the people with their hand on the kill switch.

Comment: We have tags according to what the game-playing community thinks should be treated as distinct things. The gaming community of GTA* treats V and Online as different things, therefore we tag them as different things. We are not going to have people coming here and say "I'm playing GTAO, here is my question, can someone put a GTAO tag on this?" and then tell them "No you're wrong you're playing GTAV. Tagging as such." That's just not how we do things.

Comment: @Fluttershy My faith that people are speaking from a place of knowledge and not ignorance was shattered when fbueckert revealed that a) He had actively deleted the `[GTA-Online]` tag, not because he thought it was synonymous with `[Grand-Theft-Auto-5]`, but because he thought it was the same as `[RockstarGames-Social-Club]`. And b) It became clear that a lot of those who think there should be one tag are going entirely on things they've read: The game was released on the same disk, it features the same graphics, it's made by the same company, ergo, *it's the same game*.

Comment: And a lot of those that think otherwise (that there should be two tags) are also just going in things they read.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt Regardless of your reasoning behind it, your rude/hateful comments are not constructive to the issue at hand, nor are they welcome on this site.

Comment: I am with @Fluttershy on this - be civil or don't take part.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt I find the fact that you are actively hostile against opposing viewpoints most disconcerting.  People aren't going to agree with you throughout life, and dealing with people who disagree with you is a skill everyone has to learn.  Lashing out isn't constructive, and does nothing to help your case.

Comment: @fbueckert (and others) Debating something using reason and logic is not the same as "lashing out". Attacking someone's *opinion* is not the same as attacking *someone*. You've taken what I've said about your argument to be a personal insult, when I have not engaged in "hateful" anything anywhere.

Comment: Off topic: @Fluttershy is the kindest of ponies.

Comment: Django: saying 'another person who hasn't played the game' and 'interesting. How exactly are they the same?' Is passive aggressive at best, and certainly rude.

Comment: @TZHX Wow. I'm sorry you read it that way, but I assure you that you're projecting. I ASKED if it was another person who was going on what they'd read (note the question mark) and my second comment was said with absolute sincerity and genuine interest into how you came at your opinion. I'm sorry if you thought I was being "passive aggressive" or sarcastic, but that's the absolute opposite of what I was being.

Comment: Just to re-iterate to everyone here who would like to see me hanging from a tree: I was NOT being insincere. I was *genuinely* interested in how TZHX came to his conclusions, and I was *genuinely* thankful that he'd at least played the game before posting an opinion. I'm sorry if it read as "passive aggressive" or "hostile" or "rude", but those emotions were simply not there. I had a mild sense of frustration left over from another answer which has since been deleted (where it was revealed the poster hadn't played either game), but that was it.

Comment: Just a quick response to this: TZHX: "And a lot of those that think otherwise (that there should be two tags) are also just going in things they read." Firstly, that's a huge assumption that appears to have nothing to back it up. (Whereas, there was an answer before yours where the author revealed he hadn't played either - since deleted.) Secondly, if that *was* the case, I would feel the exactly same way about what they wrote, too: I would rather they didn't post until they'd seen it with their own eyes, or at least researched it thoroughly.

Comment: A single person does not a lot of people make (unless they're Casanova). Most of the pro two tags argument is based on what rockstar and the media say (and people have read) over what is minimal differences in the game play.

Comment: @TZHX Again, this isn't worth debating but: You're making bold assumptions with seemingly nothing to back it up, whereas I'm talking about several different people who have posted things acknowledging their own first-hand inexperience (some of which has since been deleted). One of them even asked me to explain further what the differences were in the original question. So I went back and tried to do just that.

Comment: I agree, this isn't worth debating anymore.

Comment: I like extending an olive branch and then removing it, by the way. Nice touch for avoiding the passive aggressive. :)

Comment: @TZHX Hmm. I just decided not to post my personal details on the internet. It has nothing to do with you. I'm still happy to play online -- I just don't know how to get my details to you. Also, you should try not to take everything so personally.

Comment: Also, also, you should really learn what "passive aggressive" means before you use it as an insult. Being passive aggressive is like this: "I don't mind what we do, it's entirely up to you!" "Really? Ok, I really want to go bowling..." "Oh. Ok then." "You don't want to go bowling?" "No, it's fine. I don't mind." "Ok, let's do something else then." "No, it's up to you." "Great, let's go bowling!" "*audible sigh*" (The person in the example who doesn't want to go bowling is being passive aggressive:  Pretending to be passive, but actually trying to get what they want: http://bit.ly/GK6E80)

Comment: You should learn what not continuing to "debate" means as well as the ":)" symbol I ended my comment with. Chillaxe.

Answer (score -9):

I've been using the tags [grand-theft-auto-v](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-v) and [multiplayer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiplayer) in my questions about GTA online

Comment: While I don't like this approach, it definitely is consistent with what we've done for other things in the past, such as Mass Effect 3's Multiplayer.

Comment: @Sterno there was [a plan](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/5064/1351) to retag ME3 multiplayer questions.  I guess [multiplayer] was deemed to be too important.

Comment: @Sterno Mass Effect 3 and Mass Effect 3 Multiplayer weren't two separate games though...

Comment: @kalina From what I've been told (though not experienced firsthand), neither are GTA Online and GTA5, since you actually launch GTA Online through the GTA5 client. It's possible I've been misinformed. If I haven't been, the only real difference seems to be that GTA Online is marketed with its own name. Though to be clear, I'm not saying this is the best answer. I think I actually prefer two separate tags. I think we probably should have done that with Mass Effect 3 as well.