# Tag for Kenways Fleet

Tags: discussion, tags

I've noticed that my questions about the Kenways Fleet minigame in Assassins Creed 4 have been edited to remove the tag.

I'm curious as to why, being that this is a contained mini-game which is also available as a mobile app.

I think that it's availability as a mobile app is enough to differentiate so that having it's own related tag would be helpful to users.

A similar example would be a question about Chocobo World, a mini-game in Final Fantasy 8

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but from what I read in chat I'm guessing it wasn't known there was a separate mobile version.

Comment: I have re-added the tag to [these](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/144864/52800) [three](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/151486/52800) [questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/143489/52800) - feel free to add it to any more you feel require it (or let me know and I'll do it).

Comment: But is the mobile version the exactly same as in the game and do they share data?

Comment: @Assylum Yes. The mobile version allows you to access the Kenways Fleet mini-game from your mobile to dispatch ships and get success reports.

Comment: @DavidYell Then it should have the AC4 Tag, since it does not make a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't create tags for mini games as questions about these mini games are fine with just the main game tag - although I wasn't aware at the time that this was also available as a mobile app which is why the action was taken to remove the tag. It is worth noting that your similar example also doesn't have it's own tag.

With the fact that this mini game is available as a mobile app, that certainly changes things and in this instance it would be appropriate to have the additional tag for these questions as we did with the Mass Effect 3 Infiltrator companion app.

Comment: It is available both ingame and also in the companion app, but not at the same time :) So a bit of an odd case

Comment: Is the minigame actually available to people who don't have AC4? You need to progress some way through the story to unlock it.

Comment: @TZHX The mini-game isn't available to people who do not own AC4BF. As you must login to your UPlay account before being able to use the companion app. You must have also unlocked Kenways Fleet in the game to be able to use the kenways fleet part of the companion app.

Comment: @davidyell yeh, so I don't think it needs a tag, as unlike me3 infiltrator, it's entirely part of the ac4 experience.

Comment: @TZHX You should add your thoughts as an answer so that other people can upvote/downvote it. So then we can see what the consensus is.

Answer (score 0):

**No, we don't need a separate tag for this minigame.**

Unlike Mass Effect: Infiltrator, there is no game here for people who don't already have Assassin's Creed 4.

It is unlikely a question could be asked tagged with [assassins-creed-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassins-creed-4) that would cause confusion by not knowing what aspect of the game the user is asking about. The mini-game is not particularly complex, and there's only three questions on the tag now.

I don't think having a separate tag for a part of a game, that is entirely part of that game (even if it can be accessed externally, such as through a mobile app) is a good route to go down for tagging on this site.

But then, people have [disagreed with me about this before](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7760/grand-theft-auto-v-vs-gta-online/7764#7764).

---

*(I don't actually expect this to change, just putting my opinion here as suggested. I'd rather not see this become a precedent, as I don't think it works.)*