# Red Dead Redemption 2 vs Red Dead Online

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-rename-request, retag-request

Red Dead Online is the multiplayer mode of Red Dead Redemption 2 and a completely separate experience that shares some similarities with GTA Online:

- You need the base game to access it
- No content is shared between them (aside from the obvious like map and weapons)
- Is listed and marketed as a separate game on the developer site (https://www.rockstargames.com/reddeadonline/) even if is part of the base game

This can be corroborated with a quote from Game Designer Imran Sarwar [on IGN](https://www.ign.com/articles/2018/09/19/red-dead-online-devs-reveal-first-details):

> There are a few reasons for [not releasing RDO alongside RDR2 single-player experience]. The first is that even though Red Dead Redemption 2 and Red Dead Online share the same gameplay mechanics and geography, we see them essentially as separate products that will grow and evolve independently of each other.

I see this as the same problem of [GTA V vs GTA Online](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7760/199843) so I want to request some edits:

- [red-dead-redemption-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-dead-redemption-2) is left as-is
- [red-dead-redemption-2-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-dead-redemption-2-online) is renamed to [red-dead-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-dead-online)
- Questions with [red-dead-redemption-2-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-dead-redemption-2-online) get the [red-dead-redemption-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-dead-redemption-2) tag removed (currently, none of the online questions apply to the single player mode)

I know that there are not a lot of questions for RDO, but I feel that this might get problematic in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, that seems correct. I have renamed [red-dead-redemption-2-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-dead-redemption-2-online) to [red-dead-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-dead-online) and created a synonym between the two, and I've removed [red-dead-redemption-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/red-dead-redemption-2) from the two questions that had it. Keep in mind that when there are only a handful of questions and no tag wiki, anyone with the privilege to create new tags can make these small retags/renames.